# Find the complex numbers that satisfy the equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I have
$$|z-3i|={\sqrt{5}}, 0 < arg(z) \le {\frac{\pi}{4}}$$
I found
$$x^2+(y-3)^2 = 5$$
Therefore, the circle with $y=3$ and radius ${\sqrt{5}}$. But how do I use the fact about $arg(z)$?

Comment: Do you understand the relation between $arg(z)$ and angles?

Comment: If $arg(z) \in (0,\frac \pi 4]$ then (x,y) are in QI, and $y\le x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

take a picture of the circle and of the line $arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ (that is the bisector of the first quadrant in the Argand Plane). And note that this line intersect the circle in two points.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of a complex number gives the angle to the positive real axis. Can you use this for your problem?